# Is there a build system that supports hot swapping whole files or code fragments regardless of file type?

Tags: android, build

**TL;DR**
I'm an android developer and I have essentially several copies of the same app that feature slight differences.  Despite my best efforts I'm having to resort to copy-and-paste style modification for each app-copy (hereafter "flavor") whenever I need to roll out a single change to all of the apps.  This is particularly heinous in Android because of the number of languages/file-types involved in a given app - C for native code, Java for regular code, .xml files for data, layouts, and os permissions, etc.  Tricks I know to avoid copy-and-paste coding that work in Java or C alone won't extend to both at once, or over to the .xml files.  I've been using Apache ANT with some success to create a custom build/ folder on the fly and include relevant files there for different build-targets, but it's a little cludgy, and there are some cases it just can't handle.

I'm wondering if there is a build system that could handle all of this for me; I'm open to any advice, though the solution I have in mind is particular to a sort of language-independent/filesystem #include approach, which for a given flavor at build time injects either whole files into a src/ tree, or else injects code fragments into various .java, .c, and .xml template files in that src/ tree.

**A Really Long Explanation with Concrete Examples:**

Examples of the differences between flavors: in the Google Store I have to use the Google in-app purchasing sdk; but in the Amazon store I have to use the Amazon in-app purchasing sdk.  Different flavors are paired with different advertising partners.  Certain flavors require different i18n language files; or graphics and layout assets for different devices; etc. etc.  Any given flavor is essentially the base code, plus any number of these "add ons", where each add on requires a little bit of custom code and file additions to the src/ tree for that app.  Whenever I need to change an add-on, I end up having to copy-and-paste the change in each flavor of the app that uses it, which is a terrible pain.

As a concrete example, imagine I have an android game and I have implemented a custom Flurry Appcircle ad view.  This would typically involve the following:

1. The addition of `"<activity>"`, `"<service>"`, and/or `"<uses-permission>"` tags to the game's AndroidManifest.xml
2. The addition of various `"<string>"` lines for the ad in the apk's res/values-xx/strings.xml folder system, where xx is a language code (ie Spanish translations would go in res/values-es/strings.xml)
3. One or more image or layout resources in res/layout, or assets/, for the ad.
4. The actual Flurry Inc sdk in the form of a Java .jar file in libs/ - possibly multiple jar files if different hardware architectures need to be handled differently.
5. Java Code in the game's Activity class, e.g. in onStart or onStop, to query for an Appcircle ad and show it.  To avoid code duplication, I would normally write this in a base class that surrounds all code in a "if(appcircleAdsEnabled(){...}", create a default implementation of that method that returns false, and @Override and return true in various children Activity classes.

This causes a few problems:

1. The Flurry .jar is now a dependency for the base class to compile whether or not the ads are enabled or not in any given flavor. I can hope that the builder notices code or resources are unused at build time and removes it from the final apk; but there are no guarantees, and failure leads to (A) bloated final binary size and (B) potential P.R. issues or worse (especially from automated scanners searching for code inclusions - in a slightly different example, I'd have a hard time assuring the Amazon App Store that "yes Google Play Billing is there but it's not used.")
2. Because of the way Android turns resource files into java constants, and in the same way as (1), the res/* files may also become unnecessary dependencies of all games deriving from this Base Class.
3. Some libraries/methodologies I've found insist on their code being added in specific places or in specific ways which precludes the base class approach altogether.
4. For each individual game I still have to at least edit its AndroidManifest to "turn this on" and request relevant OS permissions necessary to show the ad.
5. It's tedious to remember which "add on" goes with which changes in which files.  For instance, in any given flavor's AndroidManifest.xml, I can't keep track of which permissions are needed by which add ons. If I remove the Flurry add on, do I still need the INTERNET permission for something else?

What I'm hoping exists, and what I'm asking about, is if there's some way to inject files and code fragments into/on-top-of some skeleton file system, each add-on composed of a collection of such files and code fragments and injected dynamically at build time, with the build system merging lines across multiple add ons, and handling dependency inclusion on the fly.  IE for my Flurry Ad add-on I would have:

1. Some collection of files 'FILES' that includes my xml additions to various .xml files (like AndroidManifest.xml), my code additions to various .java files (like the Activity subclass), and in some cases whole files themselves to be injected in various places (like the ad layout files)
2. In some skeleton template file tree, incomplete versions of e.g. AndroidManifest.xml, MyActivity.java, etc. with something like a language-independent #include syntax indicating that data from FILES will go there.
3. Also in that template file tree, directories in src/ with 'missing files' that will be copied in dynamically at build time from FILES
4. Some sort of build directive script for FILES indicating what goes where when this add-on is included, to take the skeleton template file tree and turn it into a fully fleshed out build/ tree.

And again, ideally it would be able to handle multiple "add ons" at the same time; ie I might have some FILES for this Advertiser, and some FILES for that billing provider, etc. etc., and a given product is just a list of which modules it includes, the build system magically knitting them together at build time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like exactly the problem the [Gradle Build Variants system](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants) was designed to solve - it handles merging multiple versions of the `AndroidManifest.xml`, resources, and Java packages together into one or more separate apps. Specifically, the [Multi-flavor variants](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Multi-flavor-variants) seem to cover your requirements for combining multiple features together in various ways.

Gradle is offered as part of [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html), an IntelliJ based IDE specifically built for Android Gradle projects. You may consider reviewing one of the many [Gradle Build guides](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/1872) if you are not familiar with Gradle.